# Deleting rows from a sqlite FTS table is slow

Tags: sql, sqlite, full-text-search

I am using **sqlite 3.8.2** and I'm trying to delete a lot of rows from **my full text table** `media_fts` with the following query:

```
 DELETE FROM `media_fts`
  WHERE docid IN
        ( SELECT id
            FROM media
           WHERE is_in_music_folder = 1)
```

The query plan the query is the following:

```
SCAN TABLE media_fts VIRTUAL TABLE INDEX 1: 
EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 0
SEARCH TABLE media USING COVERING INDEX media_idx_extra_1 (is_in_music_folder=?)
```

As you can see the index `media_idx_extra_1` is properly used.

The deletion concerns **500 000 rows** and takes **34s** which is very slow ; for a comparison, deleting the same amount of rows in the `media` database takes **89ms**.

The FTS table is pretty straightforward:

```
    CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS media_fts
        USING fts4 (
            media_id,
            album_id,
            title,
            artist,
            album_artist,
            album,
            comment,
            lyrics,
            is_in_music_folder  INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
        ) ;
```

What is wrong with my query ?

> Note: my database has been VACUUMED and ANALYZED

**Update** 
As per @ah_hau's suggestion I tried the following query:

```
DELETE FROM `media_fts`            
 WHERE docid IN        
     ( SELECT id            
     FROM media           
     INNER JOIN media_fts ON (media.id = media_fts.docid)            
     WHERE  media.is_in_music_folder = 1)
```

with the plan:

```
SCAN TABLE media_fts VIRTUAL TABLE INDEX 1: 
EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 0 
SEARCH TABLE media USING COVERING INDEX media_idx_extra_1 (is_in_music_folder=?) 
SCAN TABLE media_fts VIRTUAL TABLE INDEX 1:
```

The new query takes **54s** so not an improvement

Comment: maybe you can try join query instead of sub-query

Comment: @ah_hau unfortunately, it doesn't help

Comment: How many rows in the table, and deleted?

Comment: In SQLite, one DELETE command deletes from only one table, so that don't help. how about add index for docid in table media_fts and id/is_in_music_folder in table media.

Comment: virtual table can't be indexed, so indexeing the docid column is not possible. Besides being the built in primary key of the FTS table, I am sure that all the necessary has been done.

Comment: I tried to create a cover index as you suggested, but it didn't change anything. Not surprisingly.